# Send email from ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

how to send an email when the specified page loads...!

Comment: Consider taking some time to search for what is a very simple method

Comment: Didn't find any working one. Can you show me one?

Comment: what did you search for exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to send e-mail programmatically by using System.Web.Mail in Visual C# 2005 or in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310273)

(this is still applicable, paste the code into Page_Load)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx#Y2600) class from `System.Net.Mail` namespace to send mails.